# How to fix java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused in Storm

Tags: java, linux, hadoop, apache-storm, apache-zookeeper

I am trying to connect to a zookeeper in a remote server. Zookeeper runs in a sandbox. When I start storm it shows this message in the UI. Both my machine and the server has linux.

```
org.apache.thrift7.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at org.apache.thrift7.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:183)
at org.apache.thrift7.transport.TFramedTransport.open(TFramedTransport.java:81)
at backtype.storm.thrift$nimbus_client_and_conn.invoke(thrift.clj:75)
at backtype.storm.ui.core$cluster_summary.invoke(core.clj:477)
at backtype.storm.ui.core$fn__8014.invoke(core.clj:847)
at compojure.core$make_route$fn__6199.invoke(core.clj:93)
at compojure.core$if_route$fn__6187.invoke(core.clj:39)
at compojure.core$if_method$fn__6180.invoke(core.clj:24)
at compojure.core$routing$fn__6205.invoke(core.clj:106)
at clojure.core$some.invoke(core.clj:2443)
at compojure.core$routing.doInvoke(core.clj:106)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:139)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:619)
at compojure.core$routes$fn__6209.invoke(core.clj:111)
at ring.middleware.reload$wrap_reload$fn__6234.invoke(reload.clj:14)
at backtype.storm.ui.core$catch_errors$fn__8059.invoke(core.clj:909)
at ring.middleware.keyword_params$wrap_keyword_params$fn__6876.invoke(keyword_params.clj:27)
at ring.middleware.nested_params$wrap_nested_params$fn__6915.invoke(nested_params.clj:65)
at ring.middleware.params$wrap_params$fn__6848.invoke(params.clj:55)
at ring.middleware.multipart_params$wrap_multipart_params$fn__6943.invoke(multipart_params.clj:103)
at ring.middleware.flash$wrap_flash$fn__7124.invoke(flash.clj:14)
at ring.middleware.session$wrap_session$fn__7113.invoke(session.clj:43)
at ring.middleware.cookies$wrap_cookies$fn__7044.invoke(cookies.clj:160)
at ring.adapter.jetty$proxy_handler$fn__7324.invoke(jetty.clj:16)
at ring.adapter.jetty.proxy$org.mortbay.jetty.handler.AbstractHandler$0.handle(Unknown Source)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:928)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:549)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector$Connection.run(SocketConnector.java:228)
at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at org.apache.thrift7.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:178)
... 33 more
```

This is my storm.yaml file

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
# or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
# distributed with this work for additional information
# regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
# to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
# "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
# with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
# http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

########### These MUST be filled in for a storm configuration
storm.zookeeper.servers:
     - "**.***.*.111"
#     - "server2"
# 
nimbus.host: "localhost"


ui.port: 8080
ui.childopts: "-Xmx768m"


storm.local.dir: "/mnt/storm"
# 
# 
# ##### These may optionally be filled in:
#    
## List of custom serializations
# topology.kryo.register:
#     - org.mycompany.MyType
#     - org.mycompany.MyType2: org.mycompany.MyType2Serializer
#
## List of custom kryo decorators
# topology.kryo.decorators:
#     - org.mycompany.MyDecorator
#
## Locations of the drpc servers
# drpc.servers:
#     - "server1"
#     - "server2"

## Metrics Consumers
# topology.metrics.consumer.register:
#   - class: "backtype.storm.metric.LoggingMetricsConsumer"
#     parallelism.hint: 1
#   - class: "org.mycompany.MyMetricsConsumer"
#     parallelism.hint: 1
#     argument:
#       - endpoint: "metrics-collector.mycompany.org"
```

Comment: Make sure all required services are running. sudo /etc/init.d/hbase-master status
sudo /etc/init.d/hbase-regionserver status
sudo /etc/init.d/zookeeper-server status

Comment: yeah all services are running

Comment: something along the way is blocking the connection attempts (firewalls, need for proxy configuration)

Comment: please check with "ui.host: 0.0.0.0" this configuration setting

Comment: my first configuration was like you said my own ip for ui.host. I think the problem is not with the ui host. Its with the config for connecting zookeeper.

Comment: check zookeeper from remote machine using command `echo stat | nc zk_server 2181`. is it responding?

Comment: yeah it displays the list of clients

Comment: add `storm.zookeeper.port: 2181` also in your storm.yaml setting. And then double check your settings, `Connection refused` directly means that IP:Port provided by you is not listening anything.

Answer (score 1):

I kept having the same problem... I had to restart zookeeper all the time.
It seems like Zookeeper is very sensitive to timing and timeout issues, so increase the default tick numbers for timeout, that should help.

`initLimit=30`

`syncLimit=10`